# Magento 2.1.6 pages only partially fetched in Google Webmaster tools - Not blocked by robots.txt

Tags: magento-2.1, seo, google

I am trying to understand why when I 'Fetch as Google' for any page on my Magento 2.1.6 site in Webmaster tools I always get a 'partial' rendered page.

Google consistently reports various .js and .css files as being 'Temporarily unreachable', the main product page image is also always flagged up in this way.

However, I can click any one of the files it says are unreachable and successfully open then in the browser.

I do not believe that my robots.txt file is blocking these. Can anyone offer any advice?

> Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Here's a list:
>   URL   Type    Reason  Severity
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js  Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout-es5.js  Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/mage/validation.js  Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/matchMedia.js   Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/jquery/jquery-ui.js Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/jquery/jquery.storageapi.min.js Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/mage/apply/scripts.js   Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/engine.js   Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap.js    Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/observable_array.js Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --
>   https://www.millsmeyer.com/pub/static/frontend/meyer/millsmeyer/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes.js  Script  Temporarily
>   unreachable   --

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, it's because:

Fetch as Google can't currently fetch your URL because the server took too long to reply.
Or Fetch as Google canceled your fetch because too many consecutive requests were made to the server for different URLs.
I've witnessed this happening a few times in the past. More often than not, it's an intermittent problem that goes away after a short period of time.

Important note:

Note the URL is not unreachable for all of Google - It is just unreachable for the Fetch as Google simulation tool.

Comment: I have seen that in high configured server also we were faced such problem. 
still  we also didn't get any solution for this. May be some magento 2 bug ?
Or May be any permission issue ?